# Install x-dev & x-dev:i386 at the same time

Tags: apt

I wish to install `sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-dev:i386` or `apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev:i386` or `sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-dev:i386`. But get errors:

```
sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxkbcommon-dev:i386 is already the newest version (0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxkbcommon-dev : Conflicts: libxkbcommon-dev:i386 but 0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libxkbcommon-dev:i386 : Conflicts: libxkbcommon-dev but 0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libharfbuzz-dev:i386 is already the newest version (1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libharfbuzz-dev : Conflicts: libharfbuzz-dev:i386 but 1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 libharfbuzz-dev:i386 : Conflicts: libharfbuzz-dev but 1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anybody have idea how can I install libraries at the same time to build i386 & amd64 application at single machine?

P.S.

```
Box:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: If you look at the file list for each package ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxkbcommon-dev ) they have MANY files in common. Which version do you want?

Comment: I use default version (expect last). From my log:  ```llowing packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxkbcommon-dev : Conflicts: libxkbcommon-dev:i386 but 0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libxkbcommon-dev:i386 : Conflicts: libxkbcommon-dev but 0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed ``` Version is 0.5.0-1ubuntu2.1 suites the https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxkbcommon-dev